# Window configuration overwritten on minibuffer close

Tags: window, minibuffer, tabbar, window-configuration

Here's a really nasty Emacs bug that has pained me for a long time. In `tab-bar-mode` with two tabs open (call them "tab X" and "tab Y,")

1. Open tab X.
2. Do `C-f` or a similar command that opens the minibuffer
3. With the minibuffer open and selected/active switch to tab Y.
4. Hit `C-g` to close the minibuffer.
5. Observe that the window configuration of tab Y has been overwritten with the window configuration of tab X.

It took me an embarassingly long time to unpack this behavior. Ever since I started using Emacs (around emacs 27 era), I'd randomly have tabs dupe and I had no idea why. Now that I understand the problem, how do I fix it?

### Edit

Some relevant
info:

- For anybody not aware, the term ["window configuration"](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Configurations.html) means something specific in Emacs lingo

Comment: Consider providing more details - a recipe to reproduce, starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file). How are you switching to tab `Y`? What do you mean by the "window configuration of tab ___"? Please show such configurations.

Comment: Just checked and the steps to replicate this bug starting from `emacs -Q` are the same. Enter tab-bar-mode, create two tabs, open the minibuffer, switch tabs, close the minibuffer. The exact function to switch tabs is `tab-bar-switch-to-next-tab`

Comment: Any time you discover a bug in Emacs ("really nasty" or otherwise) you ought to `M-x report-emacs-bug` with all of the details, so that it's registered and can be fixed.  Provide all the details and the recipe from `emacs -Q` in your bug report.

Comment: "Window configuration" is one thing. But what is "window configuration of a" **tab**? That's what's not clear. In what way does a tab have its own window configuration?

Comment: Drew: in `tab-bar-mode` tabs are associated with window configurations.  Selecting a tab restores the window configuration for that tab.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, this bug was fixed in Emacs 30 six months ago.  Is it possible for you to upgrade to Emacs 30?

Comment: better to provide a link to the relevant bug report or commit to fix the bug

Comment: Second this, a link to a diff or bug report would be helpful

Comment: here is a link to the relevant bug report https://debbugs.gnu.org/64373